# Flutter - The method '|' was called on null. After hot reload it is working

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

I am pretty new in flutter. I don't know what happening in background because after hot reload its work fine. On another dart files that happens, firebase dont provide me data on initialization just after hot reload.

```
class CityServices {
      getCites() {
        return Firestore.instance.collection('cities').getDocuments();
      }
    }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  bool citiesFlag = false;
  var cities;
  int citiesCount;
  String actualCity;
```

Maybe mistake is here.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    CityServices().getCites().then((QuerySnapshot) {
      if (QuerySnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty) {
        citiesFlag = true;
        cities = QuerySnapshot.documents;
        citiesCount = QuerySnapshot.documents.length;
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: MyColors.vintageGreen,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: MyColors.background,
          title: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Válasszon települést...',
              style: GoogleFonts.barlowCondensed(
                  color: MyColors.appbarText,
                  fontSize: 26.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              children: List.generate(citiesCount, (index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      actualCity = cities[index]['city_name'];
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                CityView(cityName: actualCity)),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          title: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            cities[index]['city_name'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 18.0),
                          )),
                          subtitle: Center(child: Text('22 bejegyzés')),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
                              child: Image(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  cities[index]['img_path'],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  color: MyColors.background,
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Maybe here is the mistake? Should it be on top of dart file?

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home';
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => new _HomeScreenState();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain the issue and why it is happening, then propose few solutions.

inside `initState` you are calling `CityServices().getCites().then...` which is an `async` method.
However, when your widget is built for the first time, the data you expect from Firestore is not ready yet, thus you get `null` for both `cities` and `citiesCount`.

*Short term solution:*
make sure there is null check, display indicator while waiting for the data.

```
body: Center(
   child: (cities == null) ? 
     CircularProgressIndicator()
     : Container(...
```

Additionally, you can also refactor your `initState` to something like this

```
void getCities() async {
   var snapshot CityServices().getCites();
   setState(() {
        citiesFlag = true;
        cities = snapshot.documents;
        citiesCount = snapshot.documents.length;
      });
}

@override
  void initState() {
    getCities();  
    super.initState();
  }
```

*Long term solution:*
use `BLoC` pattern and make data loading decoupled from UI.
see [flutter_bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts) for how to implement it.

Comment: Error message has gone. But now, at the start of application, the Indicatior spinning and spinning, and my app has not started. This is my main.dart file. void main() => runApp(JaszEtlap());

class JaszEtlap extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'A JÁSZSÁG ÉTLAPJA';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: HomeScreen.id,
      routes: {HomeScreen.id: (context) => HomeScreen()},
    );
  }
}

Comment: sounds good. I just updated my answer with additional example.

Comment: btw. the way you deal with async data, aka data loaded from Firestore, needs to be decoupled from UI. For that reason, I recommend you using `flutter_bloc`, see the link shared in the answer.

Comment: plz remember to accept and vote the answer if it resolves your question.  
see guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers